# PHP constants with local scope

Tags: php

In PHP is it possible to have constants with local scope? Is yes please provide a small example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, but only using a class.

```
class Foo
{
    const BAR = 'hello, world';
}
print Foo::BAR;
```

About Kalium's comment, if you're on PHP 5.3, you can indeed also use namespaces:

```
namespace Foo;
const BAR = 1;
```